# NodeJS response end cycle

Tags: node.js, response

I am working on a function which contains basically two blocks of code managed and executed by If condition, Now If first block will be executed based on the If condition then i will send response which is inside first block but if that is not true then second block. 
Here is my code example:

```
if(user.rules == undefined){
  //algorithm
  res.status(404).json({msg: 'PRIVILEGES_NOT_ASSIGNED'})
}
//BLOCK2
res.status(404).json({msg: 'PRIVILEGES_PASSED'})
```

Now without writing Block2 into else or else if Code I just want to break the execution when response is being sent, but it is not breaking somehow, I want to know how to break after sending response back.

Comment: I used it already still next block is executing

Comment: Show us where you put that `return`

Comment: `sellCtrl.offerCounterByUser(req.user.id,function(err,sellCount){
                   if((req.user.rules == undefined || req.user.rules == null || req.body.quantity > req.user.rules.autosellingapp.itmsec) 
                     || sellCount[0].COUNT + req.body.quantity > req.user.rules.autosellingapp.limit){
                      tmp_Ctrl.addTempProduct(req,function(err,cb){ 
                      if(err) res.status(503).json(err);
                       return res.status(200).json(cb); 
                      }); 
                   } );` here is the code

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
if(typeof user.rules == 'undefined'){
  //algorithm
  return res.status(404).json({msg: 'PRIVILEGES_NOT_ASSIGNED'});
}
//BLOCK2
return res.status(404).json({msg: 'PRIVILEGES_PASSED'});
```